# Bootstrap 4 Modal on Mobile Scroll Issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When I launch a modal using Bootstrap 4, I cannot see the bottom of the content when I scroll down. Thing is, it works fine on a desktop using Chrome, Firefox, and Safari in their respective responsive web design modes. It works great.

When I pick up an iPhone and use either Chrome, Firefox, or Safari and try to scroll to the bottom, I cannot reach the bottom of the page. I think this has something to do with where the modal is being launched from the main content, but I am not entirely sure.

Can anyone share advice about this? I've been stuck on this for a few hours, and it seems like such a small issue.

Here's the CSS for context:

```
        /* @MEDIA QUERIES */
        @media (max-width: 480px) {

        html,
        body {
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .footer {
            margin-top: 10px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        #formQuestionList {
            margin: 20px 0px 0px -20px;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .modal { 
            top: 20px !important; 
            bottom: 20px !important;
            right: 5%; 
            left: 5%;
            width: auto; 
            margin: 0; 
        }

        #formsModal {
            /* padding: 100px 0px 100px 0px; */
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        #instructionsModal {
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }

        .modal-open .modal .modal-dialog {
            max-height: 100%;
        }
                    
        .video-btn, .form-btn {
            font-size: 18px;
        }

        #selectInfo {
            font-size: 13px;
        }

        #instructionsList {
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .modal-footer {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Forms Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="formsModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" id="formsDialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header formHeader">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="form-title"><span id='formType'></span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id='questionsForm'>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <ol id="formQuestionList">

                                </ol>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <button id="submitForm" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Form</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: please add the html so we can try to reproduce the issue

Comment: @EricaT. Hi, Erica. Please see above for the HTML. Thank you.

Comment: I ran your code. It looks ok on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

I removed everything in your css but the font sizes, and it fixes the issue:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {

    .footer {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    #formQuestionList {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .video-btn, .form-btn {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #selectInfo {
        font-size: 13px;
    }

    #instructionsList {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Erica. Thanks for your help, but it did not work for me.

Comment: maybe there's inherited css then, because from the code you posted I was able to reproduce the issue and these changes fixed it

Comment: Were you testing on an iPhone?